# How to combine $(x - \mu_0)^TA(x - \mu_0) - (x - \mu_1)^T A (x - \mu_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to combine

$(x - \mu_0)^TA(x - \mu_0) - (x - \mu_1)^T A (x - \mu_1)$

where

- $x$, $\mu_0$, and $\mu_1$ are all vectors of shape $m \times 1$, and
- $A$ is a matrix of shape $m \times m$

I was expecting something with $x^Tx$ cancelled out in the result, but I haven't figured it out, yet.

Suppose $A$ is invertible, I am also interested in

$(x - \mu_0)^T A^{-1} (x - \mu_0) - (x - \mu_1)^T A^{-1} (x - \mu_1)$

I thought whatever the above result is, the deduction should apply to the $A^{-1}$ case, as well.

Comment: For fixed $x$, $y \mapsto x^T A y$ is linear and $y \mapsto y^T A x$ is also linear. Thus each of the two quadratic forms expands very similarly to $(a+b)(c+d)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x - \mu_0)^TA(x - \mu_0) - (x - \mu_1)^T A (x - \mu_1) $$
is equal to
$$x^TAx - x^TA \mu_0 - \mu_0^T A x + \mu_0^T A \mu_0-(x^TAx - x^TA \mu_1 - \mu_1^T A x + \mu_1^T A \mu_1)$$
Notice that $x^T A x$ cancel out
$$- x^TA \mu_0 - \mu_0^T A x + \mu_0^T A \mu_0 + x^TA \mu_1 + \mu_1^T A x - \mu_1^T A \mu_1$$
You can combine similar terms like
$$ \mu_0^T A \mu_0 - \mu_1^T A \mu_1 + x^TA (\mu_1-\mu_0) + (\mu_1-\mu_0)^T A x $$
If $A$ is symmetric, notice that the last two terms are equal, i.e. 
$$x^TA (\mu_1-\mu_0) = (\mu_1-\mu_0)^T A x$$so we can write
$$ \mu_0^T A \mu_0 - \mu_1^T A \mu_1 + 2x^TA (\mu_1-\mu_0)\tag{1} $$
An alternative term could be achieved by realizing that 
$$(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T A (\mu_1 + \mu_0) = \mu_0^T A \mu_0 - \mu_0^T A \mu_0  +\mu_1^T A \mu_0 - \mu_0^T A \mu_1$$
again under the assumption that $A$ is symmetric, $\mu_0^T A \mu_1 = \mu_1^T A \mu_0$ hence 
$$(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T A (\mu_1 + \mu_0) = \mu_1^T A \mu_1 - \mu_0^T A \mu_0  \tag{2}$$ 
The RHS in $(2)$ are the negative of the two terms appearing in $(1)$, pretty cool huh ? 
$$ -(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T A (\mu_1 + \mu_0) + 2x^TA (\mu_1-\mu_0) $$ 
Again use symmetry, you can write
$$ -(\mu_1 + \mu_0)^T A (\mu_1 - \mu_0) + 2x^TA (\mu_1-\mu_0)  =(2x - \mu_0 - \mu_1)^T A (\mu_1-\mu_0)$$

**BONUS**

You say you are also interested in $$(x - \mu_0)^T A^{-1} (x - \mu_0) - (x - \mu_1)^T A^{-1} (x - \mu_1)$$Using similar steps and under the same symmetric assumption, you'll get
$$(2x - \mu_0 - \mu_1)^T A^{-1} (\mu_1-\mu_0)$$

Comment: Yes, A is symmetric, could you please add the even more compact form, as well?

Comment: sure I have edited

Comment: I don't see why $A^T = A$ implies $x^TA(\mu_1 - \mu_0) = (\mu_1 - \mu_0)^TAx$.  I *do* see that one side is the transpose of the other. Could you please explain?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis The transpose of a $1 \times 1$ matrix is the same matrix.

Comment: @RobertLewis but you just said it, one is the transpose of the other. 
Take $(x^TA(\mu_1 - \mu_0))^T = (\mu_1 - \mu_0)^TA^Tx $. But $A^T = A $, so $(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^TA^Tx =(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^TAx $

Comment: @Ian:  right!  Thanks!